# Issues with vsftpd user account

Tags: ftp

I just setup a new server and installed vsftpd and created a user account, when trying to log in using FireFTP it appears to accept the username/password, but it never fully connects and sits on "Working...".  It times out and attempts to reconnect with no luck. Below are the settings changes that I made.

```
anonymous_enable=NO
chroot_list_enable=NO
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
chroot_local_user=YES
```

Can you think of anything that may be causing my issue?

Comment: I think the problem is that the user account isn't being put int he correct directory.  Where can I specify this?

Comment: with the chroot settings you have the user is chrooted to their home directory when they login. As far as the ftp client is aware this is "/". Do you actually see the contents of your systems "/" directory when you connect? If so, does your user have a home directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a firewall on the server? This symptom can be caused by PASV FTP no being able to connect on a second port. Also, try connecting from a command prompt instead of a client program.

Comment: It connects from CMD.  I noticed that it puts me in the "/" directory.  Is there a place where I can specify what directory the user should be in?

Comment: If it connects from CMD then I would bet money it is a firewall issue. What OS are you running on the server? Are you connecting over the internet or on your local LAN? As for the directory, I'm not sure, I have the default config on mine and it works correctly. You might want to read through the options here http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html

Comment: I'm running CentOS and I don't believe it is a firewall issue because I'm able to connect via CMD from a remote PC.  I'll read that link to see if anything catches my eye.

Comment: The fact that you can connect from CMD and not a GUI client does point to a firewall issue. When you connect using passive FTP(which most clients do) the client trys to open a connection to the server on a different port (usually > 1024). Depending on your firewall config this will not work correctly and the client will time out. Read this: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

Comment: Yup, you nailed it.  I had to add IPTABLES_MODULES="ip_conntrack_ftp" to my /etc/sysconfig/iptables file.  Thanks so much!

Comment: np, you don't know how many times I've had issues with PASV FTP and firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

Check the log file and see if that tells you what the problem is.  Hard to say with the information you provided.

**EDIT**: ***I think the problem is that the user account isn't being put int he correct directory. Where can I specify this?"***

In the vsftpd.conf look for "user_config_dir".  For example:

- user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_config

In that directory create a file for that user named the username.  Inside that file:

- local_root=$THEIR_FTP_HOME_DIR

Answer (score 0):

Configure firewall properly its may be firewall issue.
you may check http://www.rootlocker.com/complete-configuration-vsftpd-server-access-control-implementation/ link to setup properly the vsftpd server.